# Installation of Anaconda2 on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda

While installing `Anaconda2` on `Windows 7`, there is an advanced options dialog box that asks if the user wants to `Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable` and if the user wants to `Register Anaconda as my default Python 2.7`.

[image]

However, on Windows 10, this dialog box does not appear, thus no option on whether the user wants to register Anaconda as their default Python 2.7.

I have two questions:

1) Is there a way to make this dialog box appear during a Win10 install? I'm currently installing it without Admin privileges, perhaps the `advanced options` dialog appears if I run it with Admin privileges?

2) If there is no option to have the `advanced options` dialog box show with Windows 10, is there a way to ensure that Anaconda is NOT registered as the default Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an IDE for development, you can choose what python interpreter you want for development purposes in there. To choose what python you want windows defaulting to, you just modify the Path under Control Panel=>System=>Environment Variables=>Path. On Win 10, if it isn't in there, just click on "new" and add the path to the python installation you want to use as the default interpreter. If the one you don't want is in there, just remove it. To see which one it sees as the default, just open a cmd window and type python, hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit the PATH environment variables and select which python version you want to be the default. Go to Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables.

From here, if you select 'Path' in System variables and then Edit, you can add the file path to whichever python version you want to be your default, and remove the anaconda path if it's there.